# App engine use symmetric password

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine

I want to use Aes to encrypt some data and decrypt them later. I created a jks keystore, the problem is where to read the keystore and keys password. Putting the master password in the code seems not really secure. Same thing if I put in the properties file or environment variable. I could use jasypt library to keep encrypted the master password in the properties but again I need another password and the problem again where to store it. What is the best way or guidelines in these cases? I can't use a command line input neither a command line parameter.

Another question: if I keep my keys into the Google memcache, is it secure?

Comment: You have found the biggest problem with encryption: key handling! What is the hardware platform?

Comment: No idea, the app runs on Google app engine server

Answer (score 0):

Check [Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault) project.

I don't recommend you to use Google Memcache for such things. It's pretty similar to situation, when you store your master key in database or file. However, you decide, what level of security for data you need. Sometimes, properties file is enough.